# как узнать тип сокета

Tags: c, winsock

Создан сокет:

```
mysock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

Как по mysock определить протокол и тип сокета?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте функцию [getsockopt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) с параметрами `SOL_SOCKET` и `SO_PROTOCOL_INFO`, в результате вы получите структуру [WSAPROTOCOL_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), из которой вы можете получить необходимую информацию:

```
WSAPROTOCOL_INFO socket_info; // будет содержать полную информацию о протоколе 
int size, result, protocol, socket_type;
size = sizeof(socket_info);
ZeroMemory(&socket_info, size);
result = getsockopt(mysock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PROTOCOL_INFO, (char *)&socket_info, &size);
if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("getsockopt failed with error code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
else
{
    printf("protocol: %s\n", socket_info.szProtocol); // напечатает название протокола
    protocol = socket_info.iProtocol; // будет содержать число, соответствующее протоколу в соответствии с таблицей в MSDN
    socket_type = socket_info.iSocketType; // будет содержать число, соответствующее типу сокета в соответствии с таблицей в MSDN

}
```